# Altair: custom format axis title in a Repeat

Tags: python, altair

Is there a way to access the label/title of a datum when using it in a Repeat?
I would like to change the Y-axis title by applying a custom function to the default label (simple example below).
I know I can change the columns in the dataframe or do a manual loop to get the result, but I wonder if there is a direct way using repeat.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

def replace(label):
    label = str(label)
    return label.replace('_', ' ')

source = data.cars()

alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y=alt.Y(alt.repeat('repeat'), type='quantitative', title=replace(alt.datum.label)),
    color='Origin',
).repeat(
    repeat=['Miles_per_Gallon', 'Weight_in_lbs'],
)
```

[image: original]
becomes:
[image: using a function]

Comment: I don't believe this is possible unfortunately. You can raise it as a feature request on the vega lite issue tracker on GitHub. I think they would need to add a `titleExpr` parameter to the Axis object, the same way that there is currently a `labelExpr` parameter that does take a function